# How to concatenate time and date field into one field using ArcGIS for Desktop Field Calculator or Python?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, python-parser

I have two fields, one is `ISSUEDDATE` and the other is `ISSUEDTIME`.  I would like to concatenate fields so that the `ISSUEDDATE` is in `m/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss` format.

My `ISSUEDTIME` field is a string and `ISSUEDDATE` is a date field and the `ISSUEDDATE` isn't consistent.  Some of the values read as `m/dd/yyyy 7:00:00 AM` while others are `m/d/yyyy`. `ISSUEDTIME` isn't consistent either as some are AM/PM and others are 24 hour time.

How can I accomplish this without adding a field?

I have tried to concatenate the two fields, but it fails.  Since there are two time formats, the solution below fails also.  I can execute this via selection and field calculate but would like for it to be done in one go.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest posting sample rows with all types of time and date formats to make things easier.

Comment: This is very easy to do in Excel. Just add them (don't concatenate); date is no of days since some start, time is the partial day(s). If you can't add an ArcMap field to that table, I would suggest using a testing table so you can try formats.

Comment: I don't want to do it in excel because I will lose my original objectID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in field calculator. Open a field calculator window for your field `IssuedDate`. Set the parser to Python and check `Show Codeblock`. In the pre-logic script code box enter:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

def timeconvert(timestr):
    if re.search("PM|AM|pm|am", timestr):
        newtime = datetime.strptime(timestr, '%I:%M:%S %p').time()
    else:
        newtime = datetime.strptime(timestr, "%H:%M:%S").time()
    return newtime
```

In the code box enter:
`datetime.combine(datetime.strptime(str( !IssuredDate! ).split(" ")[0] , "%m/%d/%Y"), timeconvert( !IssuedTime! ))`

That should take care of the inconsistent entries in the IssuedDate field.

Comment: When ISSUEDTIME is in 24 hour format, a ValueError is thrown for the format, how can this be resolved, otherwise I think it works for the AM/PM format.

Comment: I added a function that will parse the time in either 12 or 24 hour formats.